# How can I correctly apply SELECT DISTINCT ON to my SUM() query

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have this query:

```
SELECT SUM(change_percent) 
FROM api.security_price 
WHERE date = (SELECT MAX(date) FROM api.security_price)
AND symbol in ('AAPL','TSLA','MSFT');
```

It runs a little slow, with indexes included. Instead, I want to test out `SELECT DISTINCT ON (symbol)`.

Here is why I want to use `DISTINCT ON`:

- Performance will increase. `Max()` can slow things down.
- I need to be able to retrieve the most recent row (aka date) for each item in my `symbol` field. `DISTINCT ON` can do that if set up properly.

However, I'm failing to do so:

Here is how I try to implemenmt:

```
SELECT SUM(change_percent) 
FROM 

     (SELECT DISTINCT ON (symbol) symbol, change_percent FROM api.security_price) AS a 

WHERE a.symbol in ('AAPL','TSLA','MSFT');
```

This query is working (and its much faster), but I'm not getting the correct calculation. How can I set everything up correctly in my new query?

Comment: Please **[edit]** your question (by clicking on the [edit] link below it) and add some sample data and the expected output based on that data as [formatted text](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/251362). See [here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/356997/new-feature-table-support) for an explanation on how to create text tables. ([edit] your question - do **not** post code or additional information in comments)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your original query should be fine:

```
SELECT SUM(change_percent) 
FROM api.security_price 
WHERE date = (SELECT MAX(date) FROM api.security_price) AND
      symbol IN ('AAPL', 'TSLA', 'MSFT');
```

I would recommend an index on `(date, symbol)`.

If you want the max date *per symbol*, then the query would be:

```
SELECT SUM(change_percent) 
FROM (SELECT DISTINCT ON (symbol) sp.*
      FROM api.security_price sp
      WHERE symbol IN ('AAPL', 'TSLA', 'MSFT')
      ORDER BY symbol, date DESC
     ) sp
```

However, this is not guaranteed to be equivalent to your original query.

Comment: Thank you for your comment, yes I actually just added a index on the date, which I thought I had, thank you for letting me double check. It turns out my fist query is 20x faster than the second one with Distinct On.